# Event Tracing for Windows GUI

Tags: windows, gui

i want to view tracing events from the Event Tracing for Windows system.

As far as i can tell the only client program that exists for connecting to providers is a command line tool that comes with the Microsoft Windows Device Driver Development Kit (DDK), e.g.:

```
tracelog -start "NT Kernel Logger" -f krnl.etl -dpcisr -nodisk -nonet -b 1024 -min 4 -max 16 -ft 10 –UsePerfCounter

...

tracelog –stop
```

It then requires a separate command line tool to convert the generated log file into something usable, e.g.:

```
trcerpt krnl.etl -report isrdpc.xml
```

Has nobody come up with a Windows program (ala Performance Monitor, Process Monitor, Event Viewer) that lets me start tracing by pushing a "Go" button, let me see events, and i can stop it with a "Stop" button?

Is there GUI for Event Tracing for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 will be shipping with [redesigned pair of GUI tools](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/HW-59T) in the Windows Performance Toolkit:

- Windows Performace Recorder (GUI to start/stop tracing)
- Windows Performance Analyzer (xperf's but with a much better UI)

It's not a single easy to use gui, but it's a step. For now the answer is:

- no, there is no good gui tool
- wait for Windows 8 for an incremental improvement